# $\int_\mathbb{R} \bigg( \frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h} |f(t)| dt\bigg) dx= ||f||_{L^1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \bigg( \frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h} |f(t)| dt\bigg)  dx= ||f||_{L^1} \;\;?$$

I worked out that the equality holds for each $\chi_{[a,b]}$, therefore it holds for each piecewise constant function. By a density argument, it must hold for all functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

1. Is this correct?
2. If it were true, I feel like there must be an easier argument for this inequality; I just can't quite see it. Maybe using Hardy-Littlewood maximal inequality or Markov's inequality, etc.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your argument is correct, if you note that the left hand side of the equality is a continuous function of $f\in L^1$. Then the denseness perpetuates the equality from the simple functions to all of $L^1$.

But there is an easier argument, change the order of integration:

$$\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R} \left(\int_x^{x+h} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt\right)\,dx
&= \iint\limits_{x \leqslant t \leqslant x+h} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt\,dx\\
&= \iint_{t-h \leqslant x \leqslant t} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dx\,dt\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} h\lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt\\
&= h\lVert f\rVert_{L^1}.
\end{align}$$

Since the integrand is non-negative and measurable, the change of order of integration is unproblematic.

Comment: Thank you for the rely! And to generalize this to $\mathbb{R}^N$, what would be the right notation? $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \int_{B(x,h)} ... \rightarrow  \int_{B(0,h)}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} ... \;\;?$$

Comment: You can write that as $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \int_{B(x,h)} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt\,dx = \iint_{\lVert x-t\rVert \leqslant h} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt\,dx = \iint_{\lVert x-t\rVert \leqslant h} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dx\,dt = \int_{B(0,h)}1\,dx\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt.$$

Comment: So basically we use the fact $$ \chi_{B(x,h)} (t) = \chi_{B(t,h)} (x)\;?$$ $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(t)| \chi_{B(x,h)} (t) dt\bigg)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(t)| \chi_{B(x,h)} (t) dx\bigg) dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(t)|\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  \chi_{B(t,h)} (x) dx\bigg) dt$$

Comment: Yes, that's what we use. And that $\int \chi_{B(t,h)}(x)\,dx$ is independent of $t$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!